# Display a percentage in a label

Tags: c#, label, rounding

I am working on a C# windows application.  I have a label on my form that I want to display a calculation. Here is my code:

```
this.lblPercent.Text = (Convert.ToString(totalPercent));
```

I have the variable totalPercent defined as a double, how do I round this number to 2 decimal places?

When I run my program, 86.8245614 is being displayed in my application and I want it to display 86.82.

Susan

Answer (score 2):

Or: `String.Format("{0:0.00}", totalPercent);`

See [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/) for some examples of how to format numbers differently.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the rounding method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby.aspx

`lblPercent.Text = Math.Round(totalPercent, 2).ToString();`

Comment: totalPercent is a double value, so it needs to be cast to a decimal before it can be rounded..

Comment: Thanks Daniel,

I was on the right track, I just had the format wrong.  Thanks for your help.

Susan

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa331875(VS.71).aspx):

```
public static string Format(string format, object arg0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

' Gets a NumberFormatInfo associated with the en-US culture.

Dim nfi As NumberFormatInfo = New CultureInfo("en-US", False).NumberFormat

this.lblPercent.Text = totalPercent.ToString("P", nfi)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator(vs.71).aspx